# How can I track changes to a sheet in Google sheets using Push notifications?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, push-notification, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

How can I track changes to a sheet in Google sheets using Push notifications?
My web application should receive a notification about a change in sheet A and write to sheet B

I have to track changes in sheet A and in case of changes write data to sheet B

I used this [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push#registering-your-domain)

I have not found how to track a specific sheet and not the entire document

I am successfully getting a notification when a google sheets document changes

My problem is that I am reading and writing in the same document, when my application receives a change message on sheet A and writes data to sheet B, I get a change notification again and everything starts over (infinite loop)

Comment: About `I have to track changes in sheet A and in case of changes write data to sheet B`, in your situation, how is your Spreadsheet edited?

Comment: The sheet is edited by the user, after which my application receives a notification that the document has been changed - processes the data and writes it to sheet B via the google sheets API

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The sheet is edited by the user, after which my application receives a notification that the document has been changed`, if you want to check this, you can use the OnEdit trigger. But, if you wanted to execute the script of `processes the data and writes it to sheet B via the google sheets API` when Sheet A is edited, it is required to use the installable OnEdit trigger. In this case, you can see the existing answer. I think that it will be the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If your sheet is edited manually by a user you can create an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable):

```js
function pushNotification(e) {

  const payload = {
    cell: e.range.getA1Notation,
    old_value: e.oldValue
    new_value: e.value
    editor: e.user
  }

  const yourWebAppUrl = "https://something.com/"

  // I don't know how your web app receives information
  // so edit the request to match what you need

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(yourWebAppUrl, {
    method: 'get',
    contentType: 'application/json'
    payload: JSON.strigify(payload)
  })
}
```

If your sheet is edited not manually, but by script instead:

```js
// you can't
```

Comment: can you tell me how I can add this trigger using my app via the google API?

Comment: @АлександрХворостенко you’d have to use the Apps Script API for your given language - you can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts) but I would suggest opening a new question for this

Comment: tell me how can I link the script to the desired spreadsheets file?